# add products to the cart

Tags: php, session, e-commerce, cart

I'm following a tutorial on counting products in a cart, but at this point it doesn't work. It should increment the number every time I click the buy button, but nothing happens. The tutorial is from 2013 I don't know if it's dated.

//button buy

```
<a href='cart.php?add={$row['id_prodoct']}'><button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-small btn-block" type="button" name="button">buy</button></a>
```

//index.php -it should display a number that increases with each click

```
<h1 class="text-center my-5">number <?php echo $SESSION['prodoct_1'];?></h1>
```

//cart.php

```
if (isset($_GET['add'])) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['prodoct_'.$_GET['add']]+=1;
  header('Location:index.php');
}
```

Comment: can you link the tutorial you're following?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In cart.php put "session_start()" in the beginning of the file. Then try again to increase the counter.